# Why elevation work on marshmallow and on lollipop it doesn't

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, elevation

I'm trying to show elevation shadow on header in a expandableListView.
Its works on marshmallow (galaxy 7) and on Lollipop(galaxy 4s) is not working.
How it can be?
here is my code:

```
ViewGroup divider = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) mFloatingGroupView).getChildAt(1);
 ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) mFloatingGroupView).getChildAt(0);
        //LOLLIPOP++
                //Effect with elevation
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    if (bottom >= mFloatingGroupView.getMeasuredHeight()) {
                            if (container instanceof LinearLayout) {
                                container.setBackgroundColor(UI_Helper.getColorFromThemeAttr(getContext(), R.attr.bg_color));
                                UI_Helper.setShadow(getContext(), container, 6);
                            }
                        if(divider instanceof LinearLayout){
                            divider.setVisibility(GONE); // set divider gone
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(divider instanceof LinearLayout){
                            divider.setVisibility(VISIBLE); //set divider Visible
                        }
                    }
                }//KITKAT
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info about variables and that the code does.

Make sure that

`if (bottom >= mFloatingGroupView.getMeasuredHeight())`

is true when runing on galaxy s4.

Comment: Sure is true. i debug it.

Comment: You did not provie info what UI_Helper does.

Comment: It's only get the color and set as background to the view